# ARP Response from Virtual / Cluster IP Address

Tags: mac-address, arp, failovercluster, data-link-layer

I have a specialised hardware which is configured to communicate to a single IP address. But I want to communicate with 2 servers for SQL Server Availability Group(Both are Replicas to each other), So I make a cluster of 2 Servers (Windows Server).

For Example :

IP Address of Server 1 :      185.178.94.2

IP Address of Server 2 :      185.178.94.3

Cluster/Listener IP Address : 185.178.94.5

The Problem now is when hardware(Configured to communicate to 185.178.94.5) is sending ARP Request (i.e. asking MAC address of 185.178.94.5), the response is going from the correct server but it is going like this 185.178.94.2 has MAC address ae:23:dc:4r:2w:5r instead of going like 185.178.94.5 has MAC address ae:23:dc:4r:2w:5r.

The arp table of hardware now has entry

185.178.94.2 --- ae:23:dc:4r:2w:5r

instead of

185.178.94.5 --- ae:23:dc:4r:2w:5r

The same setup working fine if we use a normal laptop instead of our specialised hardware.

One more thing I would like to mention here is in case of hardware , if we remove LAN cable from one of the server, then packets starts coming and the arp table of hardware updated with an entry for 185.178.94.5.